# Find the name of the last day in a given month and year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to find the name of the last day in a given month and year. In this case, I am trying find the name of the last day in April, 2008. I have

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('April, 2008', 'MONTH, YYYY')) AS Last_Day
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns:

```
LAST_DAY
-----------
30-APR-2008
```

It does not give me what day of the week The 30th of April, 2008. How do I find the day of the week from a Last_Day function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date retrieved from Last_Day is no different from any other date. Use `TO_CHAR()` like so:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('April, 2008', 'MONTH, YYYY')), 'DAY') 
       AS Last_Day
FROM DUAL;
```

It will return the following:

```
LAST_DAY
---------
WEDNESDAY
```

Comment: Two things for the OP to bear in mind though: the day name will be in the session date language, though you can override that with the optional third argument to to_char; and it will be padded with spaces to the length of the longest day name in that language, unless you add [the FX modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216).